# Compare Multiple variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to compare four variables.if any two variables are same i need show an alert.
i did like the following way.

```
var a =1;
var b =2;
var c =3;
var d =4;

if((a==b)||(a==c)||(a==d)||(b==c)||(b==d)||(c==d)){
alert("Value is same, Please change the value");
return false;
}
```

Is that possible to reduce the expression to one condition instant of checking all the variables separately.Kindly advice ... TnQ in advance.

Comment: You should be using an array.

Comment: A cryptographic hash is the only way to be sure. Implement SHA-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i'll toss this into the ring, albeit it is likely not the right approach to this but it is fun. (note: browser compatibility issues and possibly over-kill is about to precede)

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 1,
    d = 3;
[a, b, c, d].sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}).reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (a == b) {
        alert('HERE');
    }
    return b;
});
```

demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Eu4qG/

further readings:
[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
[Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: While sorting is the efficient way to go about it, reducing is not appropriate here.

Comment: But... sorting isn't overkill. It's the best way to do it.

Comment: agreed, which is why I still felt the answer was warranted. but I did caution to the caveats of it(reduce to be specific). this is my first inkling to the correct answer and as it is not the best one I had noted that :)

Comment: @rlemon Thanks for reminding me about sort! Used it to make my answer more efficient than it was.. I think =)

Comment: Thanks for your support.The code working as per expectation. Once again TnQ.

Comment: Doesn't the `reduce` miss a `return b`?

Comment: @Bergi a is previousValue, b is currentValue... so no.

Comment: @rlemon: Wrong. `a` is what *previous invocation* returned (or start value), and you return `undefined`. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Eu4qG/2/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/Eu4qG/4/

Comment: good catch, I forgot to add that and due to the sort and position of my values I didn't catch it. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`while` is enough. This will work on any length of array. But the `a` array will be modified, you may need to duplicate.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
while (a.length > 1)
  if (a.indexOf(a.pop()) != -1) {
    alert("Value is same, Please change the value");
    break;
  }
```

My previous answer (in revision), which using `for`, was little embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

This checks to see if *any* of the values are the same as any of the other values:

```
var values = [a, b, c, d, e, f /* ... */];

function shared_values(values) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < values.length; j++) {
            if (values[i] === values[j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (shared_values(values)) {
    // Don't submit form or whatever
}
```

Comment: dis is more tedious then OP

Comment: @diEcho Only for small value counts. It's the same code whether you have four variables or four hundred.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to check them for you, maybe something like this:

**EDIT:** Based on other answers, you could make it more efficient with a sort

```
function areTwoEqual() {
    var arg_list = [].slice.call(arguments).sort(
        function(a,b) { return a-b; }
    );
    var vals = {};
    for(var i = 0, len = arg_list.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(vals[arg_list[i]]) {
            return true;
        }
        vals[arg_list[i]] = '1';
    }
    return false;
}

var a =1;
var b =2;
var c =3;
var d =1;

if(areTwoEqual(a,b,c,d)) {
    alert('Two values are identical!');
} else {
    alert('all values are unique');
}​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thesouthstar86/j7LmZ/

Comment: Hi brian thanks for your support.   when more than two values are same it gives two values are identical is that possible tell based on the values it should alert how many values are identical

Comment: Yes, you it could be modified to do that, but what result would you expect if your values were something like 1,1,1,3,3,5? would you want it to give you 2? or 3?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a comparison between the same element and itself

```
if (values[i] === values[j]) { }
```

I think that it should be upgraded to

```
if ( (values[i] === values[j]) && (i != j) ) { }
```

but thanks for the script